# 504 gateway timeout flask socketio

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I am working on a flask-socketio server which is getting stuck in a state where only `504`s (gateway timeout) are returned. We are using AWS ELB in front of the server. I was wondering if anyone wouldn't mind giving some tips as to how to debug this issue.

Other symptoms:

- This problem does not occur consistently, but once it begins happening, only `504`s are received from requests. Restarting the process seems to fix the issue.
- When I run `netstat -nt` on the server, I see many entries with rec-q's of over 100 stuck in the `CLOSE_WAIT` state
- When I run `strace` on the process, I only see `select` and `clock_gettime`
- When I run `tcpdump` on the server, I can see the valid requests coming into the server
- AWS health checks are coming back succesfully

EDIT:
I should also add two things:

- flask-socketio's server is used for production (not gunicorn or uWSGI)
- Python's `daemonize` function is used for daemonizing the app

Comment: Any chance your server is blocking? I assume you are using an async framework? In that case a blocking call would block the whole server.

Comment: It's very possible, although I'm not sure how to go about debugging that, because the problem only shows up seemingly randomly and I'm not sure what triggers it. For async frameworks, eventlet is used. The flask-socketio server is used for wsgi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seemed that switching to gunicorn as the wsgi server fixed the problem. This legitimately might be an issue with the flask-socketio wsgi server.